# How do I split column values into new rows at delimiter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to split the values on each row of the 1st column in a table into new rows.
The values needs to be splitted at the **/** delimiter

**-PMC90443FF/DMM/520P/C.Q5**

The above for example should be splitted as follows:

**-PMC90443FF

DMM

520P

C.Q5**

This is what I got so far.
The problem with it is that it does not delete the original line and the result is bottom to top rather than from top to bottom

```js
$('#tbl td:nth-child(1)').each(function(){
 var arr = this.innerHTML.split('/');
    var len = arr.length;
    var i;
    //$("#tbl tr:eq(1)").remove();
 for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
     $('#tbl > tbody > tr:eq(' + i + ')').clone().insertAfter('#tbl > tbody > tr:eq(' + i + ')');
  $('#tbl > tbody > tr:eq(' + i + ')').find("td").text(arr[i]);
 }
    
});
```

```css
td{
  height: 25px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:1.5;
  font-family:Courier, monospace;
  padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;}
```

```html
<script
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
<table id="tbl">
<thead>
 <tr class="tbl-header">
  <th>1</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>UWS</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>DA8101A/12.DOH</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC37516JG/DMM/1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC18713DA/DMM/2118P/C.Q4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC17854DA/DMM/1884P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC18964DA/DMM/1270P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td contenteditable="false">-PMC13312DA/DMM/1500P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC81630FF/DMM/2316P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC73647FF/DMM/2540P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC15970DA/DMM/2780P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC19458DA/DMM/2644P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC13485DA/DMM/2382P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC88130FF/DMM/2450P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC13913DA/DMM/2930P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC19689DA/DMM/3298P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PGA2002DA/ORD/2155P/C.Q5.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC11453DA/DMM/3212P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC17664DA/ORD/1800P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC90443FF/DMM/520P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC16529DA/DMM/624P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC72784FF/DMM/4218P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC94058FF/DMM/3120P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC91247FF/DMM/3466P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC38632JG/DMM/3094P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC19767DA/DMM/3778P/C.Q5</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC16397DA/ORD/1420P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC12044DA/DMM/2672P/C.Q4</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC37949JG/DMM/1672P/C.Q6</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC13278DA/ORD/928P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC11256DA/ORD/1595P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC18938DA/ORD/1458P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC12294DA/ORD/4140P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC14236DA/ORD/4136P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC13867DA/ORD/4126P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC7523DA/ORD/4152P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC18036DA/ORD/4122P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC10478DA/DMM/1548P/C.PWG</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>-PMC88389FF/DMM/1164P/C.PLD</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're missing is removing the existing row.

```js
$('#tbl tr').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var arr = $this.text().split('/');
    var len = arr.length;
    var i;
    // the first row to append new ones to
    var $previous = $this;
 for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        // create a new row as a clone of the original one
        var $tr = $this.clone();
        $tr.find("td").text(arr[i]); // set text to the column
        // append row after the previous one
        $previous.after( $tr );
        $previous = $tr;
    }
    // remove the original row
    $this.remove();
});
```

```css
td{
  height: 25px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size:12px;
  line-height:1.5;
  font-family:Courier, monospace;
  padding:2px 5px 2px 5px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl"><thead><tr class="tbl-header"><th>1</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>UWS</td></tr><tr><td>DA8101A/12.DOH</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC37516JG/DMM/1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC18713DA/DMM/2118P/C.Q4</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC17854DA/DMM/1884P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC18964DA/DMM/1270P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td contenteditable="false">-PMC13312DA/DMM/1500P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC81630FF/DMM/2316P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC73647FF/DMM/2540P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC15970DA/DMM/2780P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC19458DA/DMM/2644P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC13485DA/DMM/2382P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC88130FF/DMM/2450P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC13913DA/DMM/2930P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC19689DA/DMM/3298P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PGA2002DA/ORD/2155P/C.Q5.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC11453DA/DMM/3212P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC17664DA/ORD/1800P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC90443FF/DMM/520P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC16529DA/DMM/624P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC72784FF/DMM/4218P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC94058FF/DMM/3120P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC91247FF/DMM/3466P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC38632JG/DMM/3094P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC19767DA/DMM/3778P/C.Q5</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC16397DA/ORD/1420P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC12044DA/DMM/2672P/C.Q4</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC37949JG/DMM/1672P/C.Q6</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC13278DA/ORD/928P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC11256DA/ORD/1595P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC18938DA/ORD/1458P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC12294DA/ORD/4140P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC14236DA/ORD/4136P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC13867DA/ORD/4126P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC7523DA/ORD/4152P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC18036DA/ORD/4122P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC10478DA/DMM/1548P/C.PWG</td></tr><tr><td>-PMC88389FF/DMM/1164P/C.PLD</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem with it is that it does not delete the original line and the result is bottom to top rather than from top to bottom

You can change your code to:

```
$('#tbl td:nth-child(1)').each(function(idx, ele){
    var arr = ele.innerHTML.split('/');

    var currRow = $(ele).closest('tr');
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        currRow.clone().insertAfter(currRow).find('td').text(arr[i]);
    }
    currRow.remove();
});
```

Steps:

- get current row
- for each split element clone the row and insert after current row changing the cell text
- remove current row

```js
$('#tbl td:nth-child(1)').each(function(idx, ele){
  var arr = ele.innerHTML.split('/');
  var currRow = $(ele).closest('tr');
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
      currRow.clone().insertAfter(currRow).find('td').text(arr[i]);
  }
  currRow.remove();
});
```

```css
td {
    height: 25px;
    min-width: 30px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    font-family: Courier, monospace;
    padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
    <thead>
    <tr class="tbl-header">
        <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>UWS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DA8101A/12.DOH</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC37516JG/DMM/1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC18713DA/DMM/2118P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC17854DA/DMM/1884P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC18964DA/DMM/1270P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td contenteditable="false">-PMC13312DA/DMM/1500P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC81630FF/DMM/2316P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC73647FF/DMM/2540P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC15970DA/DMM/2780P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC19458DA/DMM/2644P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC13485DA/DMM/2382P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC88130FF/DMM/2450P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC13913DA/DMM/2930P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC19689DA/DMM/3298P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PGA2002DA/ORD/2155P/C.Q5.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC11453DA/DMM/3212P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC17664DA/ORD/1800P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC90443FF/DMM/520P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC16529DA/DMM/624P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC72784FF/DMM/4218P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC94058FF/DMM/3120P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC91247FF/DMM/3466P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC38632JG/DMM/3094P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC19767DA/DMM/3778P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC16397DA/ORD/1420P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC12044DA/DMM/2672P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC37949JG/DMM/1672P/C.Q6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC13278DA/ORD/928P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC11256DA/ORD/1595P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC18938DA/ORD/1458P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC12294DA/ORD/4140P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC14236DA/ORD/4136P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC13867DA/ORD/4126P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC7523DA/ORD/4152P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC18036DA/ORD/4122P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC10478DA/DMM/1548P/C.PWG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>-PMC88389FF/DMM/1164P/C.PLD</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Grab all of the `td` elements. Split them on the '/'. Clear the row that they are in, then loop through them, creating `td` elements for each one. Then, add them back to the row.

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('td'), td => {
    let content = td.innerHTML;
    let row = td.parentElement;
    row.innerHTML = '';
    content.split('/').forEach( c => {
        let td = document.createElement('td');
        td.innerHTML = c;
        row.appendChild(td);
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tbl-header">
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>UWS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DA8101A/12.DOH</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC37516JG/DMM/1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18713DA/DMM/2118P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC17854DA/DMM/1884P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18964DA/DMM/1270P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="false">-PMC13312DA/DMM/1500P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC81630FF/DMM/2316P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC73647FF/DMM/2540P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC15970DA/DMM/2780P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19458DA/DMM/2644P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13485DA/DMM/2382P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC88130FF/DMM/2450P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13913DA/DMM/2930P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19689DA/DMM/3298P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PGA2002DA/ORD/2155P/C.Q5.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC11453DA/DMM/3212P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC17664DA/ORD/1800P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC90443FF/DMM/520P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC16529DA/DMM/624P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC72784FF/DMM/4218P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC94058FF/DMM/3120P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC91247FF/DMM/3466P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC38632JG/DMM/3094P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19767DA/DMM/3778P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC16397DA/ORD/1420P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC12044DA/DMM/2672P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC37949JG/DMM/1672P/C.Q6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13278DA/ORD/928P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC11256DA/ORD/1595P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18938DA/ORD/1458P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC12294DA/ORD/4140P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC14236DA/ORD/4136P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13867DA/ORD/4126P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC7523DA/ORD/4152P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18036DA/ORD/4122P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC10478DA/DMM/1548P/C.PWG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC88389FF/DMM/1164P/C.PLD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the original line, you can `empty()` the element.  While you still have the elements you want to insert, append each to the now empty `tr`.

```js
$('#tbl td').each(function() {
  var $tr = $(this).parent('tr').empty();
  this.innerHTML.split('/').forEach(function(text) {
    $tr.append('<tr><td>' + text + '</td></tr>');
  });
});
```

```css
td {
  height: 25px;
  min-width: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-family: Courier, monospace;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr class="tbl-header">
      <th>1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>UWS</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>DA8101A/12.DOH</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC37516JG/DMM/1946P/C.Q4.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18713DA/DMM/2118P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC17854DA/DMM/1884P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18964DA/DMM/1270P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td contenteditable="false">-PMC13312DA/DMM/1500P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC81630FF/DMM/2316P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC73647FF/DMM/2540P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC15970DA/DMM/2780P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19458DA/DMM/2644P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13485DA/DMM/2382P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC88130FF/DMM/2450P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13913DA/DMM/2930P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19689DA/DMM/3298P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PGA2002DA/ORD/2155P/C.Q5.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC11453DA/DMM/3212P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC17664DA/ORD/1800P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC90443FF/DMM/520P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC16529DA/DMM/624P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC72784FF/DMM/4218P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC94058FF/DMM/3120P/C.Q5.DUMMY</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC91247FF/DMM/3466P/C.Q5.KIKKER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC38632JG/DMM/3094P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC19767DA/DMM/3778P/C.Q5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC16397DA/ORD/1420P/C.Q4.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC12044DA/DMM/2672P/C.Q4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC37949JG/DMM/1672P/C.Q6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13278DA/ORD/928P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC11256DA/ORD/1595P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18938DA/ORD/1458P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC12294DA/ORD/4140P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC14236DA/ORD/4136P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC13867DA/ORD/4126P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC7523DA/ORD/4152P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC18036DA/ORD/4122P/C.PLD.TRANSIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC10478DA/DMM/1548P/C.PWG</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>-PMC88389FF/DMM/1164P/C.PLD</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I guess I was'n clear enough. I need the splitted text to be put on a new line, underneach each other (row) rather than on a new column.

Comment: OK I see that you accepted an answer already, but I've updated the code! Mine also separates each into their sub-row so you could space them out/arrange them better